# Get unique value from table Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to get all rows that have one unique column. The problem with my code is that it works only when I select just that one column, but in the end I need to have multiple columns.

```
$values= Model::select('id','value_first','gender_first','value_second','gender_second')->groupBy('value_first')->get();
```

Comment: $values= Model::select('id','value_first','gender_first','value_second','gender_second')->distinct('value_first')->get();

Comment: Great, you can post your answer, thank you!

Comment: Welcome i'm posting My Answer You just vote for it to appriciate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Solution of Your Problem

```
$values= Model::select('id','value_first','gender_first','value_second','gender_second')->distinct('value_first')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Laravel Documentation you can use `distinct` method for the same

> The distinct method allows you to force the query to return distinct
>   results for e.g

```
$values= Model::select('id','value_first','gender_first','value_second','gender_second')->distinct('value_first')->get();
```

Reference: [Laravel-> Database: Query Builder -> Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)